# Display is on 42" TV on Kbuntu

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, display, hdmi

I have installed **Kbuntu** 16.04 LTS

- On Intel® Desktop Board DH55TC
- With Intel® Core™ i3 CPU 540 @ 3.07GHz
- 500 GB SATA hard drive
- **Connected to 42" LG TV with HDMI cable**
- TP-Link 300 MB USB wireless LAN
- Wireless keyboard & mouse

All drivers are installed properly, display is also nice. All is working fine.

As display is on 42" TV and I am seating far, I cannot read. Is there any utility which can make screen more readable and we can work from far or any kind of work around.

I also remember that in Ubuntu there was scaling option in display setting and in GNome Ubuntu there was zoom option, is there anything like that in Kubuntu

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open Compizconfig Settingsmanager.

Go to Accessibility / Enhanced Zoom Desktop.

Click on the "Disabled" titled Button of Zoom in, click on enable, grab key combination and press ctrl+f7. Do the same for Zoom out, and you are set. Screenshot:enter image description here